Cannot use 'plot' in local scope on trading view pine editor
When entering this code on trading views pine editor it returns "Cannot use 'plot' in local scope"
// Plot indicators
plot(sma_short, color=color.blue, title="SMA Short")
plot(sma_long, color=color.red, title="SMA Long")
hline(rsi_buy_level, "RSI Buy Level", color=color.green)
hline(rsi_sell_level, "RSI Sell Level", color=color.red)
plot(rsi, color=color.purple, title="RSI")

I was expecting to add to chart but keeps preventing me because of plot can be used in local scope

the code youpost is not enough to see the error. you refer to local scope, but your code does not have local scope
